# Swift/Xcode - UITextView and UIButtons in UIContainerView not responding to touch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicontainerview

My buttons and textviews are displaying properly inside the container view but they are not responding to clicks/taps. The container view's height is set to the regular portrait size (780). The container view is placed in a scroll view

[image: Picture]

Comment: Try to set `view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` on your containerView and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Is the outlet method not running or or delegate methods not running? If the latter, make sure .delegate is set to self

Comment: @RashwanL uer interaction is enabled in everything

Comment: @IanMoses the textbooks and the buttons itself is not responding to clicks

Comment: Is the `editable` property true?

Comment: @IanMoses where is that placed?

Comment: As an example:

textView.isEditable                      
textView.isSelectable

Comment: @IanMoses its user interaction is enabled if thats what you mean. I am using the storyboard.

Comment: userInteractionEnabled, isEditable, and isSelectable are different properties of textViews. For UIButton the property is: isEnabled.

Answer (score 0):

The view controllers you get out of the container are independent controllers. Don't forget to set delegate there.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Im fairly new to IOS programming. By delegate do you mean add the custom class to the separate view that comes with the container view?

Comment: My point is that the view controller in your container is a separate view controller, therefore all your IBOutlet or actions or delegate should be set in the controller who is in the container.